# jQuery toggle add or remove class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can you please help me figure the script needed for the adding or removing class in toggle jQuery?

what i want to attain is that, when the class="title" is clicked, the `class="item-holder"` will show up, at the same time, the div that holds the `class="title"` will also have 
class="expanded" so it will be div `class="title expanded"`, but if it will be toggled again, the `class="expanded"` will be removed. also if the the item 1 is toggled, only item 1 will show its content, and if let's say item 3 is clicked, the item 1 will close its content.. and item 3 will open its content... its like an accordion in bootstrap 3. but unfortunately i cant use bootstrap 3 on it.

[here's what i have as of now.](http://jsfiddle.net/agn9Lz4u/3/)

can anyone please show me the correct code for this?

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/agn9Lz4u/1/

```
$('.title').click(function(){
  $('.item-holder').hide()
  $('.title').removeClass('expanded')

  var title = $(this).addClass('expanded')
  var stage = title.data('stage');
  $(stage).show() 
});
```

Notice the change to the HTML as well:

```
<div class="title" data-stage="#stage-1">
```

and

```
<div class="item-holder" id="stage-1">
```

Basically you need to reset everything on a title click - remove the expanded class and hide all the item-holder divs. Then you only show the item-holder you want and re-add the expanded class to the title you just clicked.

By saving a selector in a data element you can have clicking on the title know exactly which div it should open. There are various ways to accomplish this, but this was probably the easiest with the HTML you already had and the JS you started.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
 $('.title').click(function(){
            $('.item-holder').hide(); 
            $(this).next('.item-holder').toggle();  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "expanded" ).next(".item-holder").toggle();
});
```

Here is the updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/agn9Lz4u/4/